# what is running yield?

Tags: finance

Suppose an investor who pays £120 on 15 July 2007 for £100 nominal of a six-year stock with half-yearly coupon payments of 13% pa and is not subject to tax. The stock is redeemable at par. Calculate the running yield?

I understood entire question but what actually is running yield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Running yield* is the annual income from an investment divided by its current market value.  Unless the market price is equal to the nominal price, it will not be the same as the nominal yield or the redemption yield.

So in this case  $\dfrac{13}{120}$ or about 10.83%.

Comment: Even though there are 12 half yearly coupons?

Comment: so, the running does not depend on number of periods coupons are made? Or is 10.8% for one year?

Comment: @soandos: I think [this](http://www.finance-glossary.com/define/bond-interest-yield/12344/0/B) agrees with me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_yield

Comment: yes, book has answer as 10.8%

Comment: @amul28: the market price will change over time, moving closer to £100 as the redemption point approaches, so the running yield will change.

Comment: @Henry: so, 10.8% corresponds to the coming year!

Comment: @amul28: it corresponds to the current market price and the coming year.  Tomorrow the market price will probably change, so the running yield will probably change too.

Comment: ok, got it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Used to describe the income investors get from their portfolio as a percentage of market value of the securities."

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/runningyield.asp